# How to make a collada model hollow inside?

Tags: three.js, collada

How to render only the surface geometry of a collada model in threejs.

I have a 40mb collada (dae) file that I am importing in my scene using thhreejs loader. Then I show the same model from 4 camera views and render all 4 views with basic rotation animation. Problem is, that the rendering is slow (due to the low performance mini PC I am using).

Comment: Your model is probably a mesh, meshes are hollow. If you want to improve performance decrease the number of triangles that make up your mesh, get a software that can help you with that (Blender, Maya, Houdini, etc. )

Comment: Its not a mesh and I zoom in I can see the insides.

Comment: Then you have triangles on the inside of the model, cull them.

Comment: please tell me how!

Comment: Post a picture of the model so that I could think of an algorithm.

Comment: Thank you! Here is the link to the collada file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hueo4uzXovVYlB0f7Ex5tvyP9wWUAekS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WWKmfVv_Ae8-hnd4v9svwnBLLbG5PGeF?usp=sharing) with the optimized models (in .dae and .obj). I used an [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89204/how-to-lower-the-polygon-number-but-keep-smoothness) from [blender's stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/). I managed to reduce significantly the number of vertices 73.4926% and 56.0847% of faces.

*I scaled the models to 1000X their original size, watchout for that.